# Flutter: Cloud_firestore will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, barcode-scanner

I can not use these both flutter plugins together:

```
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0+2
  barcode_scan: ^0.0.8
```

When run, error occured:

```
D8: Program type already present: android.arch.core.util.Function
     *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of cloud_firestore will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See https: //goo.gl /CP92wY for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

it compiled and runned on Android phone when I remove one of them. But both can not go together. How to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short

Add multidex library to android app dependency (/android/app/build.gradle)

```
...
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  ...
}
...
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // use latest version
  ...
}
...
```

under android directory
gradel.properties file

Add

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 2):

**Found** the solution (for me, at least) !

I had the following issue:

```
[+1498 ms] > Task :app:crashlyticsUploadDeobsRelease
[        ] > Task :cloud_firestore:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :firebase_analytics:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :firebase_auth:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :firebase_core:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :firebase_crashlytics:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :firebase_dynamic_links:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :firebase_messaging:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :firebase_ml_vision:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :firebase_remote_config:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :flutter_local_notifications:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :google_sign_in:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :image_picker:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :share:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :shared_preferences:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[+15399 ms] > Task :app:lintVitalRelease FAILED
[        ]          *********************************************************
[        ] WARNING: This version of cloud_firestore will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
[        ]          
[        ]          This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
[        ]          *********************************************************
[        ] 317 actionable tasks: 273 executed, 44 up-to-date
[ +372 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... (completed in 75.7s)
[        ] *******************************************************************************************
[        ] The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
[        ]
```

It seems that **runner** version **1.2.1** was the responsible for this !

After I changed to version **1.2.0** it worked.

So, I changed the following line from `android/app/build.gradle`

`androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.1'`

to

`androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner: 1.2.0'`

(Note: Also, don't forget to add in Firebase Console all **SHA certificate fingerprints** you are going to use in your apps.)

Answer (score 1):

Report an issue with `barcode_scan` to have it updated for AndroidX.

Limit the plugin to a version that does not depend on AndroidX until a new `barcode_scan` version becomes available:

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2
```

Or update `barcode_scan` manually like mentioned in 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28207#issuecomment-465600796