# flutter run error because of cloud_firestore androidX compatibility

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to run and have been getting an error about cloud_firestore plugin-in compatibility error. Here are the screenshots of the build and app dependencies plugins.

[image]

[image: build error]

Comment: did you try file-> invalid cache/restart -> invalid and restart ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58427419/10285344 See this answer